# How to pass params to Dropdown component from semantic ui react?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have react js code below where I put semantic ui react `Dropdown` component in a `map`. `yoe` is an array in state, I put `value={yoe[i]}`, but how can I have the index `i` being passed to the `onChange` prop? I tried the following, but the method `onAddYoe` seems doesn't recognize `i`. Can someone kindly help? Thanks!

```
              {specialties &&
                specialties.map((specialty, i) => {
                  return (
                    <div className="a-row" key={i}>
                      <div className="a-col-md-12">
                        <div className="a-text-box">
                          <label className="a-mb-5">
                            Years of experience in {specialty}
                          </label>
                          <br />
                          <Dropdown
                            placeholder="0-1 years"
                            fluid
                            selection
                            value={yoe[i]}
                            options={this.yoeList}
                            onChange={this.onAddYoe(i)}
                          />
                          {errors.email ? (
                            <span className="error">Email Required</span>
                          ) : null}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
```

Comment: What I'm seeing here is an expression that evaluates to true or false: (specialties && anArray).  Can I see more of the code?  Maybe a sandbox or fiddle or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you defined your `onAddYoe` but I am suspecting it is something like this.

```js
function onAddYoe(i) {
  // do something based on i
}
```

Then you are using it on `onChange` like so, notice that `onChange` **expects a function** but here you are **actually returning the result** of the function.

```
<
  onChange={this.onAddYoe(i)}
/>
```

You should change your function to return a function like so:

```js
function onAddYoe(i) {
  return () => {
    // do something based on i
  }
}
// or a shorter version on a functional component
const onAddYoe = (i) => () => {
  // do something based on i
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks Aivan. You are right, I didn't pass a function to onChange.